# Haskell: read and type signatures

Tags: haskell, type-inference

`read` is defined in the Prelude as

```
read :: (Read a) => String -> a
```

and can be used as e.g. `read "1" :: Int`.

Now a function

```
readOne :: (Read a) => [String] -> (a, [String])
readOne (x:xs) = (read x,xs)
```

used with `readOne ["1","foo"]` results (as expected) in the error

`Ambiguous type variable 'a' in the constraint: 

'Read a' arising from a use of 'readOne' at :1:0-18 

Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)`

But `readOne ["1","foo"] :: Int` doesn't work, while

```
readOneInt :: [String] -> (Int, [String])
readOneInt = readOne
```

works just fine:

```
> readOneInt ["1", "foo"]
(1,["foo"])
```

So: how can I add a type signature to `readOne` without defining a new function like `readOneInt`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`readOne ["1","foo"] :: Int` doesn't work because `readOne` couldn't possibly return an `Int`, it always returns a tuple, whose second element is a `[String]`. `readOne ["1", "foo"] :: (Int, [String])` will work.

Note that you only need to specify the type if it can't be inferred. If you use the result of `readOne` in a context where it needs to be an `Int`, you can use `readOne` without type annotations. Example:

```
let inc (i, strs) = (i + 1, strs) in
inc (readOne ["1", "foo"])
-- (2, ["foo"])
```

Comment: Beware! The example at the end will only work in ghci because the type of 1 is defaulted to `Integer`. If you ask ghci for the type of the expression (via `:t`), you get `(Num a, Read a) => (a, [String])` which has the same problem as before. `asTypeOf` can help here, as in `asTypeOf (readOne ["1", "foo"]) (0::Double,[]::[String])` - which I would normally write with asTypeOf in backticks but SO doesn't like doubly-escaped backticks.